# ESP8266 browning out power supply

Tags: current, esp8266

I want to setup an ESP8266 to monitor and control my hot tub's relay board. Because of where the hot tub is located, I need to modify the ESP8266 to use an external antenna (I could also order a pro). The hot tub relay board has a 5 V dc supply on it that I wanted to use to power the ESP since it's convenient.

When I power a stock ESP8266 from it, it works fine. The power reads 4.95 V and the ESP boots up. When I swap the stock ESP for the one with the modified antenna, the power reads 1.5 V an the ESP will not boot (seems like a brown out).

At first I thought my antenna mod was causing it to draw more power than original and this was exceeding the 5 V dc supply's current capability.

However - When I measure the current being drawn by the ESP when powered from a 5 V wall supply using my multimeter's inline current measuring feature, both ESPs draw 70-80 mA depending on what the wifi is doing. They measure virtually identical.

What am I missing?

Comment: RF interference from the antenna into the hot tub’s 5V power supply might be the problem. Either through the air or along the 5V wires.

Comment: the modified antenna may be shorting out the power supply

Comment: Is this an active or passive antenna?

Comment: passive antenna

Comment: @jsotola if that were the case, wouldn't it draw more power than the stock ESP?

Comment: Silly question: after testing on the wall supply did you try it on the hot tub again? There might have been a tiny short that overloaded the hot tub but the wall supply blew it out and it’s all good now

Comment: @Bryan yes I did. I also tried testing the current when powered by the hot tub, but since the voltage drops to 1.5 V the current also goes way up to 150 - 200 mA (I don't recall exact amount, unplugged as I don't want to kill the 5v supply)

Comment: Perhaps we should get some pictures up. The 1.5V really sounds like a regulator is going into current limiting which would suggest a short, unless the startup transient for your board trips it.

Comment: @Bryan inrush current is something I did not consider. Time to do some research to see if its possible to measure it with my basic 2ch scope.